# Don't send developer jobs emails at night

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I occasionally receive emails from Stack Overflow with jobs that I may like. These are great ways to hear about more opportunities, and they are useful.

But now and then the email arrives during the night and wakes me up. For example last night the email was sent at 1:15 am.

Can we schedule the emails to be sent during day time in the country where the developer is being based?

Comment: well..not everyone adds their location to their profile...

Comment: @SurajRao it can be applied only for those who have... and for others keep it as it is

Comment: Developers sleeping? That's a new thing to me.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a terribly unreasonable suggestion; while most of us receive so much E-Mail and spam at night that they have to use "do not disturb" or other mechanisms to cope anyway (or simply turn off all the respective notifications!), that may not be the case for everyone. Also it might make strategic sense for jobs E-Mails to be "new" mails delivered some time into the working day rather than wash up in the night's garbage. It would take considerable time and effort to implement, though.

Comment: What if they are on a night shift?

Comment: So now they'd have to make a custom method for you and your timezone? That can't be done. Even if it were possible, it would require a lot of time and resources.

Comment: @MartinJames could coordinate with activity on the website. If user hasn't been active for a while, assume non-night hours.

Comment: This might very well be taking the "lazy is intelligence" way too far. I mean really? Turning the sound of your phone off never crossed your mind?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier well, it happened only twice in the last 3 months and both times it was the email from stackoverflow. I never received emails this late at night before.

Comment: @user5226582 right, and if they are on rotating shifts?  Can't work, won't work.

Comment: @MartinJames rarely a system will work for everyone. I would proceed doing the lowest amount of work that targets the most people. And this would be sending the emails during the day. But if most people have their phon on do not disturb during night, that's fine.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga If you've never received emails so late at night, you're not subscribed to very many automatic email lists. It's extremely common for the jobs that send these emails to run over night.

Comment: @MartinJames This is not very common scenario. Either way, I meant sending when the user is *currently* active (on individual basis).

Answer (score 46):

Let's not.

Just set your phone to "Do Not Disturb" when you don't want to be disturbed.

Comment: Yes, or whenever you are sleeping - maybe you are on 10-2, or 2-10, or similar shift patterns,   When employed/contracted for night work, maybe driven by milestones/deadlines or by availability of databases or special hardware, you would WANT mails during the night.  This request is not something that SO should be involved with.  What next?  An SO function for no emails while user is driving?

Comment: @MartinJames: Good points. I've changed the wording of my answer a little :-)

Comment: No one mentioned a phone. I employ a guy to come and shout my emails out to me as they arrive. He takes his job very seriously and has no “do not disturb” setting. Have some thought for the more traditional amongst us.

Comment: @Clive: Do you take that guy with you to bed?

Comment: @Cerbrus he tends to go where he pleases (hopefully the tongue in cheek hasn’t been lost here, so hard to do deadpan on the net...)

Comment: Here we can see developers in their natural habitat.... jk lol